How do I calculate the posterior probability of a hypothesis given the result of the test?
I understand that the p-value is the probability of obtaining the data (or more extreme values) if the null hypothesis is true.  What researchers really want to know, however, is the probability that the null hypothesis is true given the data.  So one needs to calculate a reverse probability, based on some estimation of a base probability for the null hypothesis and weighting over something like the "total probability of obtaining the data".
I can use Bayesian inference with the sensitivity of a test, a base rate and the total number of positives:
$$\mathbb{P}(\text{sick}|\text{positive}) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(\text{positive}|\text{sick}) \cdot \mathbb{P}(\text{sick})}{\mathbb{P}(\text{positive})}.$$
For example, if a condition affects 1 person in 100, and the sensitivity of a test is of 99%, and I test 100 people at random, I get two positives (one true and one false), and an inverse probability of:
$$\mathbb{P}(\text{sick}|\text{positive}) \approx \frac{0.99 \cdot 0.01}{0.02} \approx 0.5.$$
Now, my question is, how do I use Bayesian inference for calculating the reverse probability of a p-value?  For example, I have no prior knowledge about $H_0$, so let's say $\mathbb{P}(H_0) = 0.5$, and I get a significant test (e.g., at significance level of 0.01). I would like to know how to find the posterior probability for the hypothesis in this context:
$$\mathbb{P}(H_0|\text{test}) 
= \frac{\mathbb{P}(\text{test}|H_0) \cdot \mathbb{P}(H_0)}{\mathbb{P}(\text{of what?})} 
= \frac{0.01 \cdot 0.5}{\text{?}}.$$

There is usually no valid justification to equate "no prior knowledge" with a probability of 1/2.

@whuber wouldn't the principle of indifference justify a 50:50 probability?

@dariober That's not a valid application of that principle.  The basic problem is that the probability is arbitrary, insofar as it depends on how you choose to partition the parameter space into a null and its complement (the alternative hypothesis).  The principle applies--if at all--only to situations that have a natural symmetry implying equal probability, such as a fair coin or a fair die.

You want $$P(H_0 \mid \textrm{data}) = \dfrac{P(\textrm{data} \mid H_0) \, P(H_0)}{P(\textrm{data})} = \dfrac{P(\textrm{data} \mid H_0) \, P(H_0)}{P(\textrm{data} \mid H_0) \, P(H_0)+P(\textrm{data} \mid H_1) \, P(H_1)}$$
which should not be too difficult to calculate if the conditional distributions are discrete and the hypotheses are simple.  You can easily extend this to cases where the conditional distributions have densities (i.e. are absolutely continuous) and, with more effort, to some cases where the hypotheses are composite.

There is a simple formula for the posterior probability of incorrect/correct inference when rejecting the null
One can obtain a simple and elegant posterior result by conditioning on the result of the hypothesis test (see this related answer).  Suppose you have a hypothesis test with hypotheses $H_0: \theta \in \Theta_0$ and $H_\text{A}: \theta \in \Theta_\text{A}$ and power function $\beta$.  Assuming some prior density $\pi$ for the unknown parameter $\theta$, and applying Bayes theorem gives the posterior probabilities for an incorrect/correct inference as:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(H_0|\text{Reject }H_0) 
&= \mathbb{P}(\theta \in \Theta_0|\text{Reject }H_0) \\[14pt]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(\text{Reject }H_0,\theta \in \Theta_0)}{\mathbb{P}(\text{Reject }H_0)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\int_{\Theta_0} \beta(\theta) \pi(\theta) \ d \theta}{\int_\Theta \beta(\theta) \pi(\theta) \ d \theta}, \\[18pt]
\mathbb{P}(H_\text{A}|\text{Reject }H_0) 
&= \mathbb{P}(\theta \in \Theta_\text{A}|\text{Reject }H_0) \\[14pt]
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(\text{Reject }H_0,\theta \in \Theta_\text{A})}{\mathbb{P}(\text{Reject }H_0)} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{\int_{\Theta_\text{A}} \beta(\theta) \pi(\theta) \ d \theta}{\int_\Theta \beta(\theta) \pi(\theta) \ d \theta}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
(Note that the first of these is the posterior probability of a Type II error in the hypothesis test.)  The posterior probability of an incorrect/correct inference in the test is fully determined by the hypotheses, the power function, and the prior distribution of the unknown parameter used in the test.  In general, the more powerful the test is against the alternative hypothesis, the higher the posterior probability of a correct inference when one has rejected the null hypothesis and so the lower the posterior probability of a Type II error.

I may think that researchers actually want the probability of the alternative hypothesis being true, given the data. However $P(H_A|D)=1-P(H0|D)$. To get either ($P(H_A|D)$ or $P(H_0|D)$), we use Bayes' theorem (which applies to conditional probability, whether one is a frequentist -fwiw, I am-, or not).
$P(H_0|D)=\dfrac {P(D|H_0).P(H_0)} {P(D)}=\dfrac {p.P(H_0)} {p.P(H0)+(1-p).(1-P(H_0))}$
In the above, read $D$ as shorthand for "observed data or more extreme against the null". So you have now expressed what you wanted using only $p$ (the p-value from your test), and $P(H_0)$, a "prior" (or a "prevalence", as referred to by the OP's question).
Now, how to estimate $P(H_0)$? Well, that would be the topic for a different, and longer, post. But in many cases, we can actually make a good educated guess. Just as an example, if I am comparing 2 materials to select the one with the strongest compression strength, I know that the null (both materials have exactly the same strength) is false. There is a difference, even if infinitesimal; it is just a matter of the power of my test, but I can find it.
This is the main reason why frequentist statistics compute a p-value, because it can be done w/o knowing/estimating(/guessing?) at $P(H_0)$. And this is why the same statistics do not provide $P(H_0|D)$, because for this we need $P(H_0)$.
Above, I used the p-value from the test, to express $P(H_0|D)$. But you can get to a broader formulation for all similar tests against the same $H_0$, by replacing $p$ by $\alpha$ (the size of the test selected), and $(1-p)$ by $(1-\beta)$, the power of the test.
$P(H_0|D) = \dfrac {\alpha.P(H_0)} {\alpha.P(H_0)+(1-\beta).(1-P(H_0))}$
Btw, if the above formulas look a lot like formulas for the PPV of a dichotomous test, this should be no surprise, because they are. And this should not be a big surprise, because a null hypothesis test is a dichotomous test ("do you, or not, have $H_0$", just like a dichotomous may ask "do you, or not, have Covid").
Now, describing $P(H_0)$ with words (prior?, prevalence?, true probability of $H_0$? -which is unknown, not random-, etc...) can get hairy, particularly for frequentists (Baysians would have no problem; it is a prior). But no matter, it is there...
You may be interested in the (in?)famous article by Ioanidis Why most published research findings are false, which goes over this derivation, with additional considerations, and its implications (which, not surprisingly are akin to the false positive -or base rate- paradox for dichotomous tests).
The OP's question is in fact quite insightful (+1), because it gets to why a single significant test result, particularly for a very unlikely alternative hypothesis, is not meaningful; only replication(s) of such significant tests starts to become probative (something which, in a rush to publish any result where $p<.05$, gets too often forgotten; see replication crisis).

Sorry, but this is a muddle (-1). The p-value is NOT $P(D|H_0)$ because it is an integral of 'at least as extreme'. It is not a likelihood.
No 'not the null' alternative hypothesis can be considered "very unlikely" unless the null itself is almost certain.

@MichaelLew, thanks for providing your objections for the downvote. I appreciate the courtesy. When I used $D$ in the formulas, it was meant to be shorthand for "data observed or more extreme against the null", as the OP asked to "reverse" the p value, i.e. find $P(H_0|D)$, where $D$ again is shorthand for "observed data or more extreme".  I should have made this clear. Bayes theorem applies for such a condition just as well as for a "point observation" of data. This is the reason I used $D$, and not "data", as in an earlier answer to the OP. ...ctd

...ctd. As for your 2nd objection, I am not sure I understand it? Indeed if an alternative is very unlikely, the null should be almost certain. These 2 statements are equivalent, as the alternative is "not the null" (logical complement to the null). I do not think I said anything different? I was just describing the prevalene paradox, or Lindley's paradix, if you prefer. A good example would be D. Bem's experiments on precognition, which tested a "very unlikely" alternative.

If you've re-defined the $P(D|H_0)$ to be a p-value instead of a likelihood you have made your equations false.

Sorry @MichaelLew, I do not follow; if I do not redefine $D$ (or $H_0$) between the 2 sides of the equation, how could it be false?
